# Add two hours when using strtotime

Tags: php

When I make this conversion

```
$date = '09/20/2012 02:00';
echo $stamp = strtotime($date);
```

gives me **1348099200** but when I convert it online through a website it shows the time 2 hours earlier.

How can I add 2 hours?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV An hour *does not necessarily* contain 3600 seconds.  (This is a very common error to make, and responsible for a huge number of bugs.)

Comment: @ConradShultz +1 i totally forgot that :p

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Then please delete at least your first comment. Or have you forget about where to find the delete your own comment link as well and clicking it is just no feasible for you?

Comment: @hakre i thought to let my comment for my followers who may do the same mistake, at least they will know that 1hour != 3600 seconds :)

Comment: Well you can just write: `+2 hours` - it's `strtotime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtotime` function is always relative to `now()` which is relative to a php.ini setting called timezone something (actually: `date.timezone`, see below for a link).

So you should say in which timezone your server (or website) is located, configure it and you should not need to add those two hours. These two hours even might change if the daylight saving changes, so do not encode it hard into your application.

- [`date_default_timezone_set`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)
- [`date.timezone` string<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

(Assumption: Greece UTC+2 right now, however it's summer)

Answer (score 3):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime('09/20/2012 02:00');
$date->modify('+2 hour');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d h:i');
```

Comment: I was about to suggest using `DateTime` for calendrical calculations, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it will work

`$date1 = '09/20/2012 02:00';
echo $stamp = strtotime("+2 hours",strtotime($date1));
echo date('Y-m-d h:i', $stamp);`

Answer (score 0):

What timezone are you using as a default, and what timezone is the online tool using? I am guessing that the TZ for the online tool is GMT (UTC) and yours is GMT+2, which would explain the difference.

I'd recommend setting your TZ explicitly, or use GMT based timestamps to avoid this type of ambiguity. That way you are always sure what base you are using, and TZ conversion is simple.

For example:

```
$ts = new DateTime('09/20/2012 02:00', new DateTimeZone('America/Lima'));
$ts->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
echo $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

The code above outputs:

```
2012-09-20 16:00:00+09:00
```

HTH